# Server side validation ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, validation

I need to perform server side validation for a form submission.  I need to make sure the value they enter for a course field is present in my database.  My database has a table of possible courses and a table of courses taken by a student.  In order to add a record to the course_taken table, the course must exist in the course table.  I am new to MVC and I am not sure what the best route is for doing this.  Are there any data annotations like there is for client side?  Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: You should be displaying a list of available values for the user to select from - which will effectively prevent invalid values. Let me know if you need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You would add annotations to your model class to ensure required fields are required, but in the case of checking if the course exists, use something like the following in your POST handler (assuming you are using something like entity framework):

```
if(!db.Courses.Any(o=>model.CourseId==o.CourseId)){
   ModelState.AddModelError("CourseId","Course does not exist!");
}

if(ModelState.IsValid){
//save to db
} else{
return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should create a Custom Validation annotate your property with it and when you check IsValid in your controller on your ModelState.
With this you will have less clutter in your controller and your validation will be on the right place so if change is needed you can always change.
Also if the check is from the DB add the data in the cache.